# Value inside loop doesnt change in C++

Tags: c++, nested-loops

here is a sample code that doesnt seem to work. I get the same value of X and Y ( both of them equal to zero ) for all the iteration. Can someone help me with this mistake of mine?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{

     double coord[4][2];
     int div_x, div_y;
     coord[1][0]=2;
     coord[1][1]=0;
     coord[2][0]=2;
     coord[2][1]=4;
     coord[3][0]=0;
     coord[3][1]=4;
     div_x  =  4;
     div_y  =  3;

     double a =0,b=0,c=0,d=0,e=0,f=0,g=0,h=0;
     a = coord[1][0]+coord[2][0]+coord[3][0];
     b = coord[1][0]+coord[2][0]-coord[3][0];
     c = coord[2][0]-coord[1][0]+coord[3][0];
     d = coord[2][0]-coord[1][0]-coord[3][0];
     e = coord[1][1]+coord[2][1]+coord[3][1];
     f = coord[1][1]+coord[2][1]-coord[3][1];
     g = coord[2][1]-coord[1][1]+coord[3][1];
     h = coord[2][1]-coord[1][1]-coord[3][1];

     for (int i=0; i<div_y+1; i++){  // loop all rows (blue)
      for (int j=0; j<div_x+1; j++){  // loop all nodes of one row (green)
        double w = -1 + (2/div_x)*j;
        double s = -1 + (2/div_y)*i;
        double X = (a+b*w+c*s+(w*s*d));
        double Y = (e+f*w+g*s+(h*s*w));
        cout<<"\nX "<<X<<endl;
        cout<<"\nY "<<Y<<endl;
      }
     }
     return 0;
}
.
```

Comment: change type of  div_x, div_y; to float

Comment: So debug it and find out which one of those variables is zero. 2/4 = 0 by the way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with the divisions here:

```
double w = -1 + (2/div_x)*j;
double s = -1 + (2/div_y)*i;
```

`2/div_x` and `2/div_y` are integer divisions.  When you divide two values of type integer in C++, the division is carried out as an integer division. Since `div_x` is 4 and `div_y` is 3, the result of both of them is 0. As an integer division:

```
2 / 4 = 0
2 / 3 = 0
```

The easiest way to fix this is to use a double value for one of the two values, which results in a double division. For example:

```
double w = -1.0 + (2.0/div_x)*j;
double s = -1.0 + (2.0/div_y)*i;
```

You may also want to consider using the `float` type instead of `double`, unless you really need more than `float` precision, which is about 7 decimal digits.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `div_x` and `div_y` are `int`, thus, `(2/div_x)` and `(2/div_y)` are integer divisions, and evaluate to `0`.

So `w` and `s` are both always equal to `-1`.

You can force float evaluation by using : `(2.0/div_x)` and `(2.0/div_y)`

Comment: (2.0/div_x) would not be a `float` evaluation, it would be evaluated in `double`, since `2.0` is a constant of type `double`.